# newlfm how to change closing indent

Tags: indentation, newlfm

I would like the signature to be indented past the center of the page, but not so far as the default `stdletter`. The problem with `stdletter` is that I don't have enough room to write my signature without it running into the margin.

Is it possible to change the closing's indent?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,dateno,american]{newlfm}
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}
\namefrom{Sender}
\addrfrom{123 Danton Street \\ Kalamazoo, Michigan \\ \today}
\addrto{James W. Cook \\ Electronics, Inc. \\ 123 Silicon Drive \\ San Francisco, California}
\greetto{Dear Mr. Cook:}
\closeline{Sincerely yours,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{newlfm}
        Paragraph 1

        Paragraph 2

        Paragraph 3

    \end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the `tabular` structure that is used to place the signature line. [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) sets this using

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
  ...
\end{tabular}
```

that is flushed right. Easiest is to adjust the `l`eft aligned column to be something of fixed width, like `p{.3\linewidth}` (say). The following preamble addition inserts this patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fix@one@box}{{l}}{{p{.3\linewidth}}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

You can adjust the width to suit your alignment needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,dateno,american]{newlfm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fix@one@box}{{l}}{{p{.3\linewidth}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}
\namefrom{Sender}
\addrfrom{123 Danton Street \\ Kalamazoo, Michigan \\ \today}
\addrto{James W. Cook \\ Electronics, Inc. \\ 123 Silicon Drive \\ San Francisco, California}
\greetto{Dear Mr. Cook:}
\closeline{Sincerely yours,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{newlfm}
        Paragraph 1

        Paragraph 2

        Paragraph 3

    \end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

I've always been a big proponent of not using forced letter document classes, since they can easily be duplicated using the standard `article` letter class. Personally, it feels strange declaring so much of the document content within the preamble and have only the letter contents in the body...